# StringBuilder specific case

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I'm trying to delete certain char. and trim items in a list. Here is a simple illustration of my problem.

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] s = { "Tarik \"F\"", "Tarik   ", "Tarik", "Souad  ", "Mehdi FARID", "Souad F  ", "DAFIR CCF", "khalid FA", "SAFAF" };

    char[] c = { 'F', ' ', '"' };
    foreach (string b in s)
    {
        txtDisplay.AppendText(b.TrimEnd(c) + "\n");
    }
}
```

the outcome is:

```
Tarik,
Tarik,
Tarik,
Souad,
Mehdi FARID,
Souad,
DAFIR CC: (for this item I want to keep the last 'F'),
SAFA    : (for this item I want to keep the last 'F')
```

The idea is, if the char 'F' is part of word it must not be deleted, if isolated then yes.

Comment: `TrimEnd` is not proper here. I would split the strings and check the last word.

Comment: Can you please define "Isolated"? What makes `Souad F  ` strip the `F`?

Comment: Check my answer, might be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"\W+[Ff]*(?=\W|$)");
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            txtDisplay.AppendText(regex.Replace(s, "") + Environment.NewLine); 
        }
```

This solution works no matter how many names the person has.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var results = s.Select(x =>
    String.Join(" ", x
        .Split(new [] { '"', ' ',})
        .Where(z => z != "F")));
```

I get these results:

[image: results]

Comment: Thank you it works, also a very clean code, however I have to add Trim after that, which was not the case for the first answer of Brett Sanderson.

Comment: @user2738335 - No worries. I wasn't sure if you wanted to trim at the end or whether or not you wanted to trim in-line too. I just left it out for you to put in as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] s =
             {
               "Tarik \"F\"", "Tarik   ", "Tarik", "Souad  ", "Mehdi FARID", "Souad F  ", "DAFIR CCF",
                    "khalid FA", "SAFAF"
             };
 char[] c = {  ' ', '"' };
 txtDisplay.AppendText(s.Select(s1 => s1.Split(c)).Select(l => l.Where(s2 => 
                                    !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s2) && !s2.Equals("F"))
                                    .Aggregate("", (current, s2) => current + 
                                    (current.Length > 0 ? " " + s2 : s2))).Aggregate(
                                    "", (current1, temp) => current1 + (temp + "\n")));
```